# java regex catching space or &

Tags: java, regex, java-8

I try to write a java regex pattern to match `countryname`.

The pattern can occur in two ways in a String

`"countryname=brazil  300"`

`"countryname=brazil&time=10000"`

Can you help me catch the two options? I can make two patterns if needed.

```
 pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?)countryname=(.*+)[s,(.*)]");
        matcher = pattern.matcher("countryname=brazil  ");
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("group 1: " + matcher.group(1));
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried a simple `pattern = "countryname=(\\w+)"`?

Comment: Well, if you ask me, I'd use `"countryname=(\\w+(?:[^\\w&]\\w+)*)"` (or even replace `\w` with `\p{L}`) and grab the Group 1 contents. However, you know the data and we cannot test to prove any of the solution is really working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use:

```
(.*?)countryname=([\w-]+)(.*)"
```

Comment: In the context of `matcher.find()`, the leading `(.*?)` and trailing `(.*)` are obsolete. Actually, since the code uses `while(matcher.find())`, the trailing `(.*)` must be considered *wrong*, as it may consume subsequent occurrences (if only a single occurrence is assumed, `if` should be used instead of `while`)…

Answer (score 0):

Use `\b` to match [word boundaries](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

```
countryname=\b(.*?)\b
```